# webpack-dev-server v "3.11.2" Regular expression denial of service vulnerability fix?

Tags: reactjs, security, npm, webpack-4, audit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wOwt.png)
How to resolve these two vulnerabilities reported by npm audit security report ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating my webpack to https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server/v/4.0.0-rc.0 and applied each and every change for all the 4.0.0 version in webpack worked.
Followed this docs for changes https://openbase.com/js/webpack-dev-server/versions